# Can't find System.Math namespace in ASP.NET 5 Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, class-library, asp.net-core

I am trying to build an ASP.NET 5 Class Library which uses some methods from  `System.Math`, i.e. `System.Math.Round(...)`, `System.Math.Sqrt(...)`
etc.

When I try to build it. I get following errors:

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context   ProjectName.ASP.NET Core 5.0    Class1.cs
```

I've included some packages in the project.json file to fix other error, related to `System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic`, but I couldn't fine a package that contains the `System.Math`.

Where can I find it?

Here is my project.json file:

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
},
"frameworks" : {
    "aspnet50" : { 
        "dependencies": {
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50" : { 
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22416",
            "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22416",
            "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22416",
            "System.Threading": "4.0.0-beta-22416"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Runtime.Extensions`

Use [Package Search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) to find the package containing a particular type

Comment: Not actually true. This only works if you don't user ASP Core. As with almost everything, it seems ASP Core has no support for Math.